# Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: react-native

Any head ups ? answers provided in last question didn't work out.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /home/ocode/Hututoo/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

First of all uninstall your application and close Emulator then you need to kill all node process and start npm server then run your application

**Step1:** run command `killall -9 node`

**Step2:** run command `npm start --reset-cache`

**Step3:** run command `react-native run-ios` OR `react-native run-android`

Comment: Thanks for your response but it still didn't work. The app is working fine, the error is at console, i'm not able to resolve the error. 

Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /home/ocode/Hututoo/.: 
None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index 
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency 
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency

Comment: can you share me screenshot of your error code